# Error staging application: App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase in HWC Buildpack

Tags: asp.net, .net, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, buildpack

I am trying to deploy my application built in ASP.Net 4.6.1. So I am using HWC Buildpack.
Below is my manifest.yml

```
---
applications:
- name: DRSN
  random-route: true
  memory: 128M
  buildpack: 
    https://github.com/cloudfoundry/hwc-buildpack.git
  env:
    DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT: 1
    DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE: true
```

The error that I am receiving is below.

```
Waiting for API to complete processing files...

Staging app and tracing logs...
   Cell 0f7012eb-9e32-4fdf-ba92-85aee4639139 creating container for instance 34107c3c-1acb-4aa5-b435-b06516abcfcb
   Cell 0f7012eb-9e32-4fdf-ba92-85aee4639139 successfully created container for instance 34107c3c-1acb-4aa5-b435-b06516abcfcb
   Downloading app package...
   Downloading build artifacts cache...
   Downloaded build artifacts cache (231B)
   Downloaded app package (19.5M)
   Failed to compile droplet: Failed to compile droplet: fork/exec /tmp/buildpackdownloads/6c6dca8d638ac0d145d6581f9eb9a96a/bin/compile: permission denied
   Exit status 223
   Cell 0f7012eb-9e32-4fdf-ba92-85aee4639139 stopping instance 34107c3c-1acb-4aa5-b435-b06516abcfcb
   Cell 0f7012eb-9e32-4fdf-ba92-85aee4639139 destroying container for instance 34107c3c-1acb-4aa5-b435-b06516abcfcb
Error staging application: App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase
```

Can anyone help me resolve this issue? Am I not correct in my manifest.yml? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the problem is that you're telling the system to use the HWC buildpack, but at the same time you're not setting the Windows stack (at least based on what info I can see). That means it's going to default to the Linux stack, which I believe is why you're seeing the `fork/exec /tmp/buildpackdownloads/...` error.

Try adding `stack: windows` to your `manifest.yml` or `-s windows` to your `cf push` command (for future reference, when you need help always include the full `cf push` command you're running).

PS: you shouldn't use `https://github.com/cloudfoundry/hwc-buildpack.git` that is telling the system to grab the master branch in whatever state it's currently in. That's a.) not reproducible and b.) not guaranteed to be in a working state. You should either use the platform provided buildpack names (from `cf buildpacks`) or append `#<branch_or_tag>` to the end of the URL so it picks a specific branch. All CF Buildpacks have tags for each release. It's strongly recommended you use a tagged release.

Comment: I tried using the stack: windows part in my manifest.yml. It gives the below error. "Stack 'windows' not found
FAILED"
Because of that  ro use -s windows in my cf push

Comment: Also I did not find any hwc buildpack in cf buildpacks. Which buildpack should I use for .Net framework 4.6.1?

Comment: If you run `cf stacks` and don't see `windows` listed (or an older variant like `window2016`) that means your Cloud Provider has not installed the Windows support and you *cannot* deploy a Windows app. Sorry, there's nothing you can do except ask your Cloud Provider to make it available or switch providers.

Comment: Not having the HWC buildpack present is another sign that your Cloud Provider hasn't installed the Windows Support.